# Run tail -f for a specific time in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tail

I need a script that will run a series of `tail -f` commands and output them into a file.
What I need is for `tail -f` to run for a certain amount of time to grep specific words. The reason it's a certain amount of time is because some of these values don't show up right away as this is a live log.

How can I run something like this for let's say 20 seconds, output the grep command and then continue on to the next command?

```
tail -f /example/logs/auditlog | grep test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

```
timeout 20 tail -f /example/logs/auditlog | grep test
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -f /example/logs/auditlog | grep test &
pid=$!
sleep 20
kill $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
for (( N=0; $N < 20 ; N++)) ; do tail -f /example/logs/auditlog | grep test ; sleep 1 ; done
```

EDIT: I misread your question, sorry. You want something like this:

```
tail -f /example/logs/auditlog | grep test
sleep 20
```