# AIX Shell function to tail a log file for a specific string or for a specific time

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I am searching for a way to accomplish this on our AIX v7 platform. I do not have a strong unix(AIX) background, but am trying to write bash scripts to preform repetitive functions.

Very simply, I would like the bash script to wait until a certain string appears at the end of the log.   The string could already exist in the log elsewhere.

I have read responses to similar questions and the answers are using options not available on our system. Here are the responses I have found: 
1) uses read (-t option not available in our AIX version)
[Shell function to tail a log file for a specific string for a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983572/shell-function-to-tail-a-log-file-for-a-specific-string-for-a-specific-time)

2) Uses pstree (pstree not installed) 
[Unix to tail solution for waiting for a specific string or quitting after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971121/unix-to-tail-solution-for-waiting-for-a-specific-string-or-quitting-after-a-time)

3) Uses timeout (timeout is not installed)
[Run tail -f for a specific time in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368382/run-tail-f-for-a-specific-time-in-bash-script)

4) Uses tail --pid (--pid option is not available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
tail -f -n0 "$yourfile" | grep -ql "yourstring"
```

on my Linux, this works (almost) as expected. `tail -f -n0` produces all lines that are added to the file, `grep -ql` quietly looks for a single match of "yourstring" in its input and exits afterwards.

Comment: Thank you,  I was spending way too much time on the tail command and its options.   I did not even look at options for grep.   Your suggestion is working for me.